Difference between the count in a dataframe and tempview that created from that dataframe
Step 1
I have one dataframe created from a delta table.
Df= spark.read.format(delta).load(path)

Step2
I am creating a temp view from that dataframe
Df.createorreplacetempbiew(dfview)

Now when I am performing count for this to object it's showing different count
Select count(*) from dfview---value1

%sql
Select count(*) from Df---value 2

Can anyone please help me why I am getting difference in value 1 and Value

CAN YOU ADD SAMPLE DATA

spark.catalog.clearCache() using this clear cache before execution

If your DataFrame (Df) has been cached in memory before the createOrReplaceTempView step, the cached version may not reflect any updates or changes to the underlying Delta table.

Clear the cache before querying the temporary view or the DataFrame for a fresh count::

spark.catalog.clearCache()

Also, please check the count of rows in data Frame using count() function. Spark Count is an action that results in the number of rows available in a DataFrame.
 df.count()

